# Facing Issue in writing selenium code for a webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to automate below website just for practice using selenium or protractor but facing the issue selecting the drop-downs in the form. It contains some hidden DIVs which i am not able to select as a normal list.

When we select the options from first list then second list appears.
https://www.mercurymagazines.com/pr1/100/10000

i tried below in protractor code for selecting the item

```
element(by.cssContainingText('option', '20,000-49,999')).click();
element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Computers/Internet/Tech')).click();
```

although its selecting the item in the list but second list is not coming by code.

Need help to automate the second page of the website using either selenium or protractor.

Comment: Do you mean the second list is not refreshing based on the selection in first list using the above code for 1st list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your given code can select option from drop down list.It is to select option from HTML element **SELECT**, but it's size is **1*1**.

It is so small that selenium treat it's invisible and selenium can't manipulate invisible element on web page.

Actually, the expanded options of drop down list after you click is added dynamically at the end of page near by the **BODY** tag.

Your code should includes two steps to choose option:

**1)** click on the drop down to expand its options.

```
// click on Company Size drop down
element(by.css('div.form-group.company-size')).click();
```

**2)** choose option from the HTML DOM node add dynamically to the end of page.

```
element(by.cssContainingText(
           'span.select2-container--open[style*="absolute"] li', 
           '20,000-49,999')
).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below options. In the below approach you do not need to click on the dropdown and select the value.

```
const industry = element(by.css('div.form-group.industry > span'));
const companySize =  element(by.css('div.company-size > span'));

companySize.sendKeys('20,000-49,999');
industry.sendKeys('Computers/Internet/Tech');
```

Comment: it failed with below error: 
Failed: element not interactable

Comment: It is a wait issue .Update your implementation of my answer in the question to give better idea.